# How to call an actionsheet on a bar button item

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,
i want to call to an action sheet on my left bar button item which is present on my bottom toolbar.How can i do that

Comment: You mean you want to view a UIActionSheet when Left bar item Clicked?

Comment: yes but i have a problem i  have created a controller that inherits from uitableviewcontroller and i have written a code that calls action sheet on barbutton item on toolbar but it gives me an error.                        mapType = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"MAP TYPE"                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(chooseMapType:)]autorelease];                   self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space, addButton, removeButton,mapType, nil];
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar];

Comment: - (IBAction)chooseMapType:(id)sender {
 UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map Type"                delegate:self             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"           destructiveButtonTitle:nil             otherButtonTitles:kMapTypeRegular, kMapTypeSatellite, nil];
 [sheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
 [sheet release];
}

this is my method which i have passed to my selector .

Comment: - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 NSString *clickedButtonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
 if ([clickedButtonTitle isEqualToString:kMapTypeRegular]) [[self mapView] setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
 else if ([clickedButtonTitle isEqualToString:kMapTypeSatellite]) [[self mapView] setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
}
this i my action sheet method but it is not getting called and giving me an error that -[UIActionSheet _presentSheetFromView:above:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UIActionSheet.

Comment: Can you please post all previous comments on your Question to be more readable and i am ready to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button to run 'myButtonPressed' and then use the code..

```
- (void)myButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet* action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                         initWithTitle:@"Menu" 
                         delegate:self 
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Quit" 
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Debug",nil ];
[action showInView:self.view];
[action release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:   (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0: // continue
        NSLog(@"Continue");
        break;
    case 1: // Quit
        NSLog(@"Quit");
        break;
    case 2: // Debug
        NSLog(@"Debug");
        break;
}
}
```

In the .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```